# how to select mutiple files in IE explorer?

Tags: html, file, internet-explorer, button

I want to select multiple files in IE with a button. Are there any simple methods? IE doesn't support HTML5 tag which is unbelievable. Thank you!

Comment: how do you select multiple files in other browsers?

Comment: In chrome. I use <input>tag multiple attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Include several `<input type=file>` elements. You could also create such elements dynamically with JavaScript so that once a user has selected a file, a new file input element appears.